# SalesForce Opportunity Field inset Error

Tags: java, web-services, salesforce

I am integrating with salesforce through java there in Opportunity there is a field named CloseDate .
my code for the same is 
`opportunitySObject.setField("CloseDate", "2010-01-01");` 
but i get `message='Close Date: value not of required type: 2010-01-01'
 statusCode='INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD'`

what i see by quering the database is CloseDate in `2010-01-01` format i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If this is java code, try passing an actual Date value instead of a string. Your SOAP stack (Axis, CXF, etc.) will serialize the date into the proper wire format.

This advice is really for the Enterprise API. If you're using Partner API, it could be a little different.

Comment: Excellent. If you think the solution would be useful to others, please add it as an answer to your question. Thanks.

Comment: I used the built in Date function in Java and this worked for me. Thanks for your help!